# Unable to generate allure directory files and report using webdriverio + typescript for appium mobile automation

Tags: mocha.js, appium, webdriver-io, allure

I have a webdriverio project that is setup with the following for mobile automation using appium:

- typescript
- mocha
- allure

When I run the following line of code, after npm install, the test will run but no allure-results files will be produced in the directory:

```
npm run android-tests
```

At one point, I reverted and attempted to follow the documentation outlined [here](https://webdriver.io/docs/typescript/) using the webdriverio docs to add the types for the framework and services to my tsconfig.json types property, as well as install its type definitions. It did not work, and then I reverted the code back to its original state

My Project is located here 'https://github.com/amad410/webdriverio-appium-sampleProject'